# Update duplicates records with different values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 temporary tables

tempA:

```
attr1   | attr2   |  attr3    |   expense
 ab         bc       8967         4567
 ab         bc       4543         922.65
 ab         bc       3476         7878.2
```

tempB

```
attr4   | attr5   |  attr6    |   revenue
ab          bc        8967         25.1
ab          bc        4543         25.2
ab          bc        3476         25.3
ab          bc        8967         25.4
ab          bc        3476         25.5
```

I have a third temp table, #tempC
this table is built based on #tempA and #tempB tables.

The issue that I am facing is that #tempC is storing these:

```
attr1  |  attr5  |   revenue  |  expense
ab         bc         25.1        4567
ab         bc         25.2        922.65
ab         bc         25.3        7878.2
ab         bc         25.4        4567
ab         bc         25.5        7878.2
```

it assigns expense everytime there is match between attr3
and attr6(it should do it when the match is for the first time)

so I need this for #tempC

```
attr1  |  attr5  |   revenue  |  expense
ab           bc       25.1        4567
ab           bc       25.2        922.65
ab           bc       25.3        7878.2
ab           bc       25.4        0
ab           bc       25.5        0
```

in this case if there is a match again between attr3 and attr6
it should store 0.

How could I solve that.

(attr3 and attr6 are varchar and they are not pk, or fk they are just simple attributes)

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @Steven . . . Your results seem to depend on an ordering of the rows.  However, tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no ordering.  Do you have an ordering column?

Comment: SQL Server. I updated the question.

Comment: So you need an update statement to fix the problem or an insert statement?

Comment: @Shaquidur  I have no started yet but what about:                                         
     insert into tempC
     select
 attr1, 
 att5, 
 attr6, 
 rev, 
 IIF(attr3ExistFunction(tempC, attr3),0, expense ) 
                                                                                                                                          I do not know if that is a good idea

Comment: I need an update statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below query for required output.With the help of window function we can achieve it easily.

```
create table #tempA (attr1 VARCHAR(10), attr2 VARCHAR(10), attr3 VARCHAR(10), expense NUMERIC(18,2))

create table #tempB (attr4 VARCHAR(10), attr5 VARCHAR(10), attr6 VARCHAR(10), revenue NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #tempA
VALUES('ab', 'bc', '8967', 4567),
      ('ab', 'bc', '4543', 922.65),
      ('ab', 'bc', '3476', 7878.2)   

INSERT INTO #tempB
VALUES('ab', 'bc', '8967', 25.1),
      ('ab', 'bc', '4543', 25.2),
      ('ab', 'bc', '3476', 25.3),
      ('ab', 'bc', '8967', 25.4),
      ('ab', 'bc', '3476', 25.5)


 select distinct attr1,
   attr5,
   revenue,
   case when b.rn = 1 then expense else 0 end as expense 
 from #tempA a
 join (select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by attr6 order by attr4,attr5,attr6) as rn from #tempB ) b 
    on b.attr4 = a.attr1 
      and b.attr5 = a.attr2 
      and b.attr6 = a.attr3
```

Comment: It worked but I have a doubt. if I insert this:                                                                      #tempA('ab', 'bc', '', 4513.31) into #tempA table, it does not add the 4513.31 in the final table. I tested changing join for left join but nothing changed. I suspect it is for b.rn = 1 condition..